PolarDB 11 compiles vops plugin and reports an error
PolarDB 11 compiles vops plugin and reports an error, but PolarDB 15 compiles vops and reports no error.
Because VOPS can help PolarDB accelerate the performance of OLAP scenarios, vops should be used in PolarDB.
The specific reproduction method is as follows:

Set Up the PolarDB Development Environment:

1.1. Pull a Docker image of the PolarDB development environment for an operating system you are familiar with, such as Ubuntu 22.04:
docker pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/polardb_pg/polardb_pg_devel:ubuntu22.04    

1.2. Create and run a container:
docker run -d -it -P --shm-size=1g --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --privileged=true --name polardb_pg_devel registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/polardb_pg/polardb_pg_devel:ubuntu22.04 bash    

1.3. Access the container:
# 进入容器 
docker exec -ti polardb_pg_devel bash

1.4. Clone the PolarDB 11 source code and compile the PolarDB-PG instance:
# 例如这里拉取 POLARDB_11_STABLE 分支;   
# PS: 截止2024.9.24 PolarDB开源的最新分支为: POLARDB_15_STABLE    
cd /tmp     
git clone -c core.symlinks=true --depth 1 -b POLARDB_11_STABLE https://github.com/ApsaraDB/PolarDB-for-PostgreSQL    
  
# 编译PolarDB 11并初始化实例  
cd /tmp/PolarDB-for-PostgreSQL    
./polardb_build.sh --without-fbl --debug=off    
    
# 验证PolarDB-PG    
psql -c 'SELECT version();'      
    
            version                 
--------------------------------    
 PostgreSQL 11.9 (POLARDB 11.9)    
(1 row)  
  
# 在容器内关闭、启动PolarDB数据库方法如下:     
pg_ctl stop -m fast -D ~/tmp_master_dir_polardb_pg_1100_bld       
pg_ctl start -D ~/tmp_master_dir_polardb_pg_1100_bld      


Download VOPS Source Code in the Container:

cd /tmp  
git clone -c core.symlinks=true --depth 1 https://github.com/postgrespro/vops  


Compile VOPS:

cd /tmp/vops  
USE_PGXS=1 make install  

Outputs the following::
vops.c: In function ‘vops_window_accumulate’:  
vops.c:4338:62: error: macro "ereport" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2  
 4338 |                         errhint("Update vops to version 1.1"));  
      |                                                              ^  
In file included from /home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/postgres.h:53,  
                 from vops.c:1:  
/home/postgres/tmp_basedir_polardb_pg_1100_bld/include/server/utils/elog.h:122: note: macro "ereport" defined here  
  122 | #define ereport(elevel, rest)   \  
      |   
vops.c:4335:9: error: ‘ereport’ undeclared (first use in this function)  
 4335 |         ereport(ERROR,  
      |         ^~~~~~~  
vops.c:4335:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in  
make: *** [<builtin>: vops.o] Error 1  

